# How to generate terrains in real time?

Tags: opengl, c++, glsl, terrain, rts

I am trying to make a terrain editor for my Empire Earth OpenGL clone engine. Are there any articles of how to generate terrains in real time? It would be cool if it had pseudocode, even cooler if it had C++, and the best would be if it had OpenGL code too. But none of these are really necessary. I just need to be able to understand how real time rendering is done.

Any ideas?
[Here is a video of the terrain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DHPiGvyJ2Q)

```
for (int i = 0; i < VERTEX_COUNT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < VERTEX_COUNT; j++) {
            vertices[vertexPointer * 3] = (float)j / ((float)VERTEX_COUNT - 1) * SIZE;
        
        GLfloat height = getHeight(j, i, pData, texture_height, texture_width, channels);
        heights[j][i] = height;
        vertices[vertexPointer * 3 + 1] = height;
        
        vertices[vertexPointer * 3 + 2] = (float)i / ((float)VERTEX_COUNT - 1) * SIZE;
        normals[vertexPointer * 3] = 0;
        normals[vertexPointer * 3 + 1] = 1;
        normals[vertexPointer * 3 + 2] = 0;
        textureCoords[vertexPointer * 2] = (float)j / ((float)VERTEX_COUNT - 1);
        textureCoords[vertexPointer * 2 + 1] = (float)i / ((float)VERTEX_COUNT - 1);
        vertexPointer++;
    }
}
for (int gz = 0; gz < VERTEX_COUNT - 1; gz++) {
        for (int gx = 0; gx < VERTEX_COUNT - 1; gx++) {
            int topLeft = (gz*VERTEX_COUNT) + gx;
            int topRight = topLeft + 1;
            int bottomLeft = ((gz + 1)*VERTEX_COUNT) + gx;
            int bottomRight = bottomLeft + 1;
            indices[pointer++] = topLeft;
            indices[pointer++] = bottomLeft;
            indices[pointer++] = topRight;
            indices[pointer++] = topRight;
            indices[pointer++] = bottomLeft;
            indices[pointer++] = bottomRight;
        }
    }
```

This is the terrain creation code(modified version of an example from the OpenGL shader Cookbook). I am aware that this function is called each frame. I have successfully been able to lift the terrain by modifying values such as"vertices[vertexPointer * 3 + 1]."

Comment: Are you asking how to __generate__ terrain or how to render it?

Comment: perlinnoise <-- random a terrain map

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/replicating-minecraft-world-generation-in-python-1b491bc9b9a4
here

Comment: @tkausl I am trying to figure out how to render the terrain in real time. For example, I am trying to figure out how to render a terrain where you can increase the height at one location, and it would increase the terrain height without having to refresh again each frame. I can edit the height without having to redraw the entire terrain.

Comment: @TimChang Im not really looking for a random terrain, but a terrain that can be edited.

Comment: `it would increase the terrain height without having to refresh again each frame.` It has to refresh some things, send new data to the GPU in some way or another, otherwise this editing just won't work. `I can edit the height without having to redraw the entire terrain.` You do realize you're redrawing the entire terrain every frame anyway, right?

Comment: Hmm... right, but without going through the for loops to redraw the terrain. I maintain the terrain heights as part of the terrain height values, but sadly editing those does not work.

Comment: _"but sadly editing those does not work."_ It looks like you already have _something_. You should show us what you have and what you have tried.

Comment: "Are there any articles about..." is a question for a search engine. In this case, [the web is *packed* with hits for procedural terrain generation](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=procedural+terrain+generation&ia=web). It's expected that users will do that kind of search themselves before asking here.

Comment: @DMGregory Oh? Could you provide me with one? I have not yet been successful in such endeavors.

Comment: @Vaillancourt would it be helpful if I posted a video of what the engine looks like currently?

Comment: @Vaillancourt I just happened to upload a video to youtube about it.

Comment: ... then show it to us? Also show us the relevant code. The more you give us pertinent details, the better the help you will get.

Comment: @Vaillancourt Done. I even mentioned what paradigm I used to make the terrain.

Comment: The question is unclear: you currently have the code to generate the terrain. What do you mean by "real time"? A RTS is a _real time_ strategy game, meaning that your reflexes have to be sharp because the game goes on whether you act on it or not. A 3d game is a _real time_ software, meaning that the software reacts immediately to user input and it is displayed to them right away.

Comment: Do you want the terrain to be modified during gameplay, or only during the editing phase of your game? To me, it sounds like you're only missing ~2 features. 1) Assuming your getHeight function generates the height using a noise function, you need to save this data after the first time you've generated your terrain. It's a 2d array you can save to a binary file once you exit your program. The subsequent times you "render" your terrain, instead of using this function, you go fetch the data in the array you set aside. Then when you modify the height, you modify the values in the array.

Comment: 2) You'll need to fix the normal vectors of your vertices after each time you modify the terrain. I won't explain how to do so because [there is plenty of stuff about it](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=calculate+vertex+normal+of+a+mesh).

Comment: @Vaillancourt Yes. Specifically, I want to be able to modify the terrain while in the terrain editor. And yes, the getHeight function does what you guessed. And, so, basically, I would need to pull all that data into a std::vector and then modify it there. And then after that, render the heights, or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting off from the code you posted, you're right: this code will generate the terrain, then will be used for rendering. And you'll likely "generate" your terrain each frame.

Since you want to edit your terrain, you'll need to extract the data, then save it.

An option for you is to generate your terrain offline first: take this loop that generates the terrain, move it to a new small program that will generate the height for each vertex, then save it to disk in a binary file.

Then within your editor you will load this "height map" from disk into memory (into a vector); when you'll generate your terrain mesh, you'll refer to this vector to set the height.

The next step will be to generate the normal vectors for the mesh. Internet is [full of info on this](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=calculate+vertex+normal+of+a+mesh) so I will not explain how to do it here.

Then you'll need to find a way to deform your terrain by changing the height of each vertex**. After each time the terrain is deformed, you need to recompute the normal of the involved vertices. (At first, you can just recompute them all, it shouldn't be too costly.)

Once you're done with your session of terrain edition, you need to save your map again back to disk, so that it can be loaded and edited again in your terrain editor, or so that it can be loaded in your game.

---

<sup>** You can try your favourite SimCity game and try to understand how they do it as a first pass.</sup>

Comment: Right, so I have created the new variable, which is responsible for all of the vertex information of the terrain. It decreased the frame rate to 10 FPS.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something about your explanation?

Comment: "Then you'll need to find a way to deform your terrain by changing the height of each vertex**. After each time the terrain is deformed, you need to recompute the normal of the involved vertices. (At first, you can just recompute them all, it shouldn't be too costly.)" That was the point of the question.

Comment: "move it to a new small program that will generate the height for each vertex, then save it to disk in a binary file." are you implying that I should go create another program just for this data?

Comment: Though I *do* appreciate the information you have provided for me, I still am not quite understanding what you are getting at.

Comment: @rjhwinner03 If there's something that you find unclear about the provided answer, please specify what that is and the provider of the answer might be able to explain that either in this comment section (although the comment section isn't supposed to be used for extended discussion) or by editing the  existing answer to add an explanation on the thing(s) that you find unclear.

Comment: "It decreased the frame rate to 10 FPS" that sounds like a problem with your implementation, not a problem with the advice to cache and re-use the generation result. We won't be able to help you find your mistake unless you show the code.

Comment: I am still a bit confused, @Daniel_1985 , about what he means about "generating the terrain each frame." I post the terrain code to a VAO and then render it, but all the VAO stuff is done before the rendering process.

Comment: @rjhwinner03 What I think Vaillancourt mean by "generate your terrain every frame" is based on the fact that you would like to be able to alter/change the terrain at runtime, like in an editor. To be able to see the changes made to the terrain, after it's been altered, the terrain data that has been previously uploaded to the GPU needs to be replaced by the new terrain data. So you'll basically need to update the VBO containing the vertex data of the terrain. If the terrain will never change though, you only need to upload the terrain data once, during the startup of the game/application.

Comment: @Daniel_1985 Yes.

Comment: @rjhwinner03 You might want to edit your question and provide an [MCVE](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2202/40264). It's very hard to help with the small amount of info you're providing us.

Comment: @Daniel_1985 OHHH OK cool! I got it!

Comment: Thank you all! I am just going to polish it up a bit.

Comment: @rjhwinner03 Once you're done with this "infrastructure", and it works, you could ask a new question with just that: how do I modify the terrain height in the context of a terrain editor.

Comment: @Vaillancourt good idea!